# Is there a raster function to reverse the x and y axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster

I have a raster dataset that I created from iwd. I have plotted a filledContour plot but I want to reverse the x- and y-axis so that the numbers are decreasing, eliminate the white space and vertically exaggerate the y-axis.  Setting the xlim and ylim as you would in ggplot or plot has not worked.

If there is no way to reverse the x- and y-axis of a raster dataset, how do I maintain the resolution of my s4 class dataset after converting to s3? For example, if I use `filled.contour` instead of `filledContour`.

Here is my code and plot, which is pretty basic because what I have tried has not produced any results:

```
idw.out <- gstat::idw(Z ~ 1, core2, grd, idp = 1.5)
r <- raster(idw.out[1])
r.contour <- filledContour(r)
r.contour
```

[image: filledContour plot]

An example of the scale that I am looking for is below:

[image: contour plot]

Cheers

Comment: What is `core2` ?

Comment: The data was collected from a floodplain sediment core. I did, nevertheless, solve my problem and posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem with the code listed below. Because I had S4 class data, I had to manually set the axis extent to coincide with the xlim and ylim. This step is not required for 'filled.contour' plots, but is for 'filledContour' plots.

## interpolated grain-size data from core2

```
idw.out <- gstat::idw(Z ~ 1, core2, grd, idp = 1.5)
```

## conversion to raster

```
r=raster(idw.out[1], layer = 1, values=TRUE)
```

## add colour scheme and plot

```
b = c(0,5,10,15,20,30,40,50)
col = rev(bpy.colors(length(b)-1))
r.contour = filledContour(r, zlim=c(0,50), xlim=c(9,-4), ylim=c(5.3,0),
                          asp = NA, xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", las = 1,
                          col=col, levels=b,
                          xlab="grain-size (phi)", ylab="core depth (m)", main="Core 2")
```